# React-table - how do I trigger a hide/close of a subcomponent

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Using the mouse it is easy to hide/show subcomponents using React-Table (v6.6) . But I want to hide my subcomponent after a form submission, for example. The only way to do this I've found is to manage the expanded components like this:

```js
<ReactTable
  data={data}
  expanded={this.state.expandedNotes}
  onExpandedChange={(newExpanded, index, event) => { this.setState({expandedNotes: newExpanded}) }}
/>
```

However, when I do this I have a new problem, which is that these indexes in `expanded` are page-specific, not data-specific. So when I change page or filter, subcomponent X will stay open, even though this isn't the original subcomponent.

It seems I can manage this by adding controls to close the subcomponents on all events:

```js
<ReactTable
  data={data}
  expanded={this.state.expandedNotes}
  onExpandedChange={(newExpanded, index, event) => { this.setState({expandedNotes: newExpanded}) }}

  ...

  onPageChange: this.closeAll,
  onPageSizeChange: this.closeAll,
  onSortedChange: this.closeAll,
  onFilteredChange: this.closeAll,
  onResizedChange: this.closeAll,
  onExpandedChange: this.closeAll,
/>
```

But this seems heavy-handed. Is there a setting to stop the subcomponents from staying open on these changes?

I tried with:

```
        collapseOnSortingChange={true}
        collapseOnPageChange={true}
        collapseOnDataChange={true}
```

But they didn't work. Those are the default settings anyway though.